# Undefined (Discord.js, Cherrio)

Tags: javascript, discord

Суть такова. Я не программист, поэтому три дня уже парюсь с как мне кажется простой чушью.
Мне нужно чтобы код забирал с кода элемента сайта информацию о чём-то: название, описание, дату, ссылку. Но он отправляет только "Undefined". После, всё должно отправляться по embed в дискорд.

````
const botSettings = require("./botsettings.json");
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const fs = require("fs");
const prefix = botSettings.prefix;
const axios = require('axios');
var $ = require( "jquery" );
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
bot.login("XXX");
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot is ready! ${bot.user.username}`);
});

bot.on("message", async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
})

const url = ('XXXXX')

function init() {
    console.log("Initializing");

}

let link;

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html),

       link = $('head [a="area-label"]')
        .attr("href")

        console.log(link)

    }})



bot.on('message', message => {

if (message.content === '!test') {


const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("XXX")
                .setURL(link)
                .setDescription("Описание")
                .setColor(0x00AE86)
                .setImage(`XXX`)

                message.channel.send(embed);
}})```
````